# Rollback a set of Oracle stored procs from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, rollback

I have a set of storred procs in Oracle that save a user's information into a number of different tables.

If any of these fail, I want to rollback the changes. However, there is a commit statement within each stored proc.

Can I / How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Control your transaction from your Data Access Layer and remove the commit transaction from your PL/SQL scripts / packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //Do all your SP work here

    scope.Commit();
}
```

You need a reference to System.Transactions, also.

If something fails, an exception will be thrown and everything will get rolled back.  The "using" statement will automatically dispose the scope and rollback.

Comment: the using does the dispose, the dispose rolls back any uncommitted transaction...

Comment: does this solution also require that I remove the commits from the stored procs? I would prefer not to, just incase someone else tried to use the stored proc and does not put the commit statement in their code.

Comment: No you shouldn't have to remove them, transactions can be nested.  I would still give it a test to be sure, as with any solution.

Comment: Cool, I'll try it out. And just to be clear, I should have all my try-catch block inside of the using block?

Comment: What library do i have to import to get Transaction Scope... visual studio is complaining it does not know what TransactionScope is...

Comment: Try-catch outside of the block.  Add a reference to System.Transactions, I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: If the commit has happened in the database, then nothing C# can do will reverse that. Oracle doesn't have the concept of nested transactions in the way SQL Server does

Comment: Of course, that he should still try it.  I suspect TransactionScope and the ADO provider for Oracle might do some magic to make it work.